# Determine duplicates based off minimum N characters from smaller comparing string

Tags: c#, string, linq, duplicates

I have two lists, both containing models that share a common field, ID(String value). I am comparing the ID's for duplication.

I currently have a LINQ statement in place to determine the duplicated ID values, which stores them into a list of strings:

```
List<string> duplicateRecords = testData.TestRecords.GroupBy(aa => aa.ID).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(y => y.Key).ToList();
```

And a second LINQ statement that maps a List of respected models based off the duplicated ID LINQ result:

```
List<Model> modelRecords = testData.Models.Where(x => duplicateRecords.Any(y => x.ID == y)).ToList();
```

These two LINQ statements do exactly what I expected them to do which is great. But now there is a recent request to determine duplicate ID's based off of their minimum N characters during a comparison. This minimum N comparison must happen for the last N characters in a string.

**EX)**

- **ID1:** 123 == **ID2:** 123
- **ID1:** 0123 == **ID2:** 123
- **ID1:** 123 == **ID2:** 0123
- **ID1:** 1230 != **ID2:** 123
- **ID1:** 123 != **ID2:** 1230
- **ID1:** 122110123 == **ID2:** 123

Hopefully those examples give some insight into the problem I am trying to solve. This could be done using `foreach` loops but I have come to experience the code becomes very messy and unmanageable on complex list query's.

**So my question is this:** *How can I use the last N characters of the smaller of the two comparing strings to determine duplicates using LINQ?*

**Note:** I am also very open to more *elegant ways* of solving this problem, would really appreciate excluding any `for` or `foreach` solutions.

Comment: Basically you just want the comparison to determine if the longer string ends with the shorter string?  If so, you could write a custom `IEqualityComparer<string>` that would do the comparison.  The only difficulty is trying to determine the hash, but if you have a minimum value for N then you could just hash on the last N characters.

Comment: if the input values are `123` and `0123`, should the result have the first, the second, or both of them?

Comment: @PiotrŁazarczyk the result should return a collection of models that contain the last n values of the flagged duplicate ID. I may be aware that the initial determination of a duplicate value in my first linq statement might not be accurate since it is a hard comparison.

Comment: @juharr this is an interesting suggestion but there is an ongoing issue that I cannot simply assign a known N value for which we can substring.

Comment: @Jimi can you explain what the [N] is doing? im not familiar.

Comment: @davedno The comparison part of the code wouldn't need a hard defined N as you'd just determine it from the shorter string.  But you also have to implement a hash, and there knowing a minimum N would help.  Since hashes only need to be equal for equal values, but can also be equal for unequal values.  But you'd want to limit the hash collisions as much as possible.

Comment: I can't help but feel this is some form of borderline _code improvement/review_ style question because you want to use LINQ instead of `foreach`.  Not sure if this is on-topic for SO?  It is interesting though

Comment: @MickyD I can understand that, but the question is trying to extend on what code is already in place to implement a new feature, not to optimize or improve the code. +1 none-the-less.

Comment: Are `TestRecords` and `Models` actual `List`s? You are using LINQ to Objects? Is there a unique id value in `TestRecords` class?

Comment: Also, how do you want to handle multiple matches for differing lengths? What should the answer be for `"123", "4123", "23"`? Is it `"23"` or `"23", "123"`?

Comment: @NetMage Presumably you'd take the shortest as it's the one that will "match" all of them.

Comment: @juharr That would be rather more tricky I think.

Comment: And is it possible to have actual complete duplicates in your source `ID`s? e.g. if you have `"123","234","123"` presumably you want `"123"` in the answer? For `"123","4123"` what answer do you want, and which Models? Both `"123"` and `"4123"` or any that match `"123"` at the end?

Comment: That's quite ok @davedno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when the input contains `123` and `0123` you want the result to have both of them

```
var input = new List<Model>()
{
    new Model {ID = "123"},
    new Model {ID = "0123"},
    new Model {ID = "1230"},
    new Model {ID = "12"},
    new Model {ID = "122110123"}
};

var result = input.Where(x => input.Any(y => y != x && (y.ID.EndsWith(x.ID) || x.ID.EndsWith(y.ID)))).ToList();
\\this will return 123, 0123 and 122110123
```

If you want to check agains existing `duplicateRecords` list then this should work:

```
List<Model> modelRecords = testData.Models.Where(x => duplicateRecords.Any(y => x.ID.EndsWith(y) || y.EndsWith(x.ID))).ToList();
```

Comment: Note: this will be slow on large collections

Comment: This is great! This could potentially be the answer im looking for, but will allow other users to comment their opinions. +1

Answer (score 1):

In order to efficiently find the duplicates you need to sort the `ID`s by length so you can minimize the comparisons necessary. (The sort adds some overhead, but greatly decreases the comparisons that must be done - in my test where 9 IDs have and 3 are duplicates of 8 values, it is 15 comparisons sorted versus 42 unsorted.) Once you have them sorted by length, just compare each one to the ones that are equal to or longer (in case of complete duplicates) to find which short `ID`s need to be kept, marking any matches so you can skip them and then find all the `Model`s that end with the found matches.

Create the `List` of `ID`s ordered by their length:

```
var orderedIDs = testData.TestRecords.Select(tr => tr.ID).OrderBy(id => id.Length).ToList();
```

I don't think there is any way to do this efficiently with LINQ, but a nested `for` loop skipping previous matches optimizes the search for duplicates.

First, variables to keep track of `ID`s`and which`ID`s have already matched:

```
var dupRecordSubIDs = new List<string>();
var alreadyMatched = new bool[testData.TestRecords.Count];
```

Now loop through the IDs and save the shorter matching IDs:

```
// foreach ID in length order
for (int n1 = 0; n1 < testData.TestRecords.Count-1; ++n1) {
    // skip the ones that already matched a shorter ID
    if (!alreadyMatched[n1]) {
        // remember if the shorter ID was alrady added
        var added_n1 = false;
        // compare the ID to all greater than or equal length IDs
        for (int n2 = n1 + 1; n2 < testData.TestRecords.Count; ++n2) {
            // if not previously matched, see if we have a new match
            if (!alreadyMatched[n2] && orderedIDs[n2].EndsWith(orderedIDs[n1])) {
                // only add the shorter ID once for new matches
                if (!added_n1) {
                    dupRecordSubIDs.Add(orderedIDs[n1]);
                    added_n1 = true;
                }
                // remember which longer IDs are already matched
                alreadyMatched[n2] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now find all the `Model`s that match one of the IDs with a duplicate:

```
var modelRecords = testData.Models.Where(m => dupRecordSubIDs.Any(d => m.ID.EndsWith(d))).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume ID is string. If so, you can do this :

```
string match = "123";

var duplicate = list.Where(x=> x.Substring(x.Length - match.Length) == match).ToList();
```

Comment: Match needs to represent a collection of models where we are comparing their field "ID" which is a string to another collection of models with field "ID". Since this is expressed in a lambda expression we simply cannot just extrapolate Match as a hard value.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, it looks to be just a matter of chopping off the last N characters in each `ID` property while grouping.

Something like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class TestRecord
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class TestModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var N = 3; // This is where you define the desired N length
        var rand = new Random();

        var testRecords =  new TestRecord[]
        {
            new TestRecord {ID = "123"},
            new TestRecord {ID = "0123"},
            new TestRecord {ID = "1230"},
            new TestRecord {ID = "122110123"},
        };

        var testModels = new TestModel[]
        {
            new TestModel {ID = "123"},
            new TestModel {ID = "0123"},
            new TestModel {ID = "1230"},
            new TestModel {ID = "122110123"},
        };

        bool SortEm(string a, string b) => a.Length < b.Length ? b.EndsWith(a) : a.EndsWith(b);

        var models = testRecords
            .Where(record => testRecords.Any(target => record.ID != target.ID && SortEm(target.ID, record.ID)))
            .ToDictionary(
                key => key, 
                key => testModels.Where(testModel => SortEm(key.ID, testModel.ID)).ToArray());

        foreach (var kvp in models)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"For duplicate key ({kvp.Key.ID}) found models: \r\n\t{string.Join("\r\n\t", kvp.Value.Select(x => x.ID))}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is kinda what im looking for but the hard assignment of N to be an arbitrary value is where this answer falls short. We need to take the data that is being compared and determine an N based off the smaller of the two comparing strings. N in your sample codes needs to be dynamic in its value so either the left or right comparing string can be the N value based off its length.

Comment: You should really post the code in the answer and not just via a link.

Comment: @davedno you mean to take the shorted of the 2 compared values and check if the tail of the longer is equal?

Comment: **Moderators:** disregard vote as poster has posted code now

Comment: @EugeneKrapivin I didn't down vote, but before you added the code down votes were definitely justified.

Comment: It was me and I have un-done the downvote now thanks

Comment: @EugeneKrapivin Exactly! Thats exactly what I am looking to accomplish.

Comment: @davedno and to be exact the comparison of the first linq query or the second?

Comment: @EugeneKrapivin The second linq query is where the magic happens. This is where we need to capture the models that match these duplicate IDs(using the minimum N) to perform other operations to them.

Comment: @davedno I think thats what you asked for. However, this is quite a naive solution and will not work well for large collections. I think that for a bigger solution I'd try to use a suffix tree of sorts

Comment: @EugeneKrapivin it is almost exactly what I was asking for but determining that N instead of defining it is what I am ultimately asking.

Comment: @davedno the definition of N is irrelevant just need to duplicate the logic, I'll edit. Form what I understood from the duplicate keys should be found, then for each duplicate key we try to find the model ID by comparing the tail of the longer ID to the shorter